# Best way to save lots of streaming data from iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, io, metal

Currently, I am streaming image and depth data from my iphone X and doing a series of computations on it using a compute metal kernel. The output every cycle (frame) is approximately 900,000 floats. Assuming there are 30 cycles (frames) a second, this represents 27million floats a second.

I would like to save a few seconds (3-5) of this data to a file, which I can then access later.

My current approach of writing the output every cycle is too slow (I/O is expensive) and I am not sure how to buffer the results of a few cycles correctly (I tried creating an array of arrays but then run into memory issues).

Copy data from mtl buffers:

```
    //number of elements per frame approx 300,000
    size_t len = elementCount
    finalArrayX = new float [len];
    finalArrayY = new float [len];
    finalArrayZ = new float [len];

    //MTLBuffers
    finalArrayX = (float*) resultsBufferX.contents;
    finalArrayY = (float*) resultsBufferY.contents;
    finalArrayZ = (float*) resultsBufferZ.contents;

    writeToFile(finalArrayX, finalArrayY, finalArrayZ)
```

writeToFile:

```
    /*
    * Get file handle to append to 
    */

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentTXTPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: documentTXTPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: documentTXTPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }
    NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:documentTXTPath];
    [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];

    /*
    * Create strings and write line by line
    */

    for(int k = 0; k < elementCount; k ++){  

        NSString *x_i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", finalArrayX[k]];
        NSString *y_i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", finalArrayY[k]];
        NSString *z_i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", finalArrayZ[k]];

        NSString *temp = [line stringByAppendingString: x_i];
        temp = [temp stringByAppendingString: @" "];
        NSString *tempTwo = [temp stringByAppendingString: y_i];
        tempTwo = [tempTwo stringByAppendingString: @" "];
        NSString *tempThree = [tempTwo stringByAppendingString: z_i];
        NSString *totalLine = [tempThree stringByAppendingString: @"\n"];
        [myHandle writeData:[totalLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
```

Whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: A mobile phone is for simple and non memory consuming tasks. For your case, more suited to a high performance computer. That said, another way I can think of is to push data to cloud. But not sure of your data retrieval/saving time constraints cause it will be slow also.

Comment: @GeneCode Given you can save video and take 12MP images, I think a few seconds is pretty feasible